# Mass vs weight, referring to property of a human body

Tags: vocabulary

If you want to ask a person what is their body mass or weight in kg or pounds, what is the proper thing to ask?

Options:

1. What is your mass?
2. What is your weight?
3. How much do you weigh?
4. What is the mass of your body?
5. What is the weight of your body?

context: academic environment, doctors appointment

Comment: [what their body mass is]

Comment: The answer can be readily found in introductory physics textbooks: the relevant physical property is, strictly speaking, mass, but using *weight* is fine for the purposes of everyday communication, given that almost all human interaction takes place at or near the surface of the Earth.

Comment: When you go to a doctors appointment, you get weighed. The only way of measuring your mass in a doctor's office is to measure its weight. Some medical terminology refers to *mass*, as in *body mass index*, but I can't imagine someone asking *What is your mass today?* instead of *How much do you weigh?*

Comment: This would be more appropriate for English Language Learners, but I see that it has already been addressed there multiple times, e.g.: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/121583/how-heavy-are-you/121588 and https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/85717/can-we-use-how-heavy-to-ask-for-a-persons-weight-is-it-appropriate/85731

Comment: I'd judge the two contexts given to be very different. In an academic environment, the common, loose usage of 'weight' is inappropriate, and weights should be given/requested in newtons (or, historically, 'pounds weight'). But when the man jumps off the Clapham omnibus and arrives for his doctor's appointment, "Do you know your weight in kg / in pounds?" is idiomatic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, you probably wanted to say that the loose usage is inappropriate in the academic environment of the natural sciences. In the academic literature for which the mass/weight distinction is not relevant, such as most of the scholarship in the humanities, the loose usage of *weight* is generally accepted.

Comment: @jsw29 I didn't, but concede that I'm on a loser here.